# Kali 2 interrupted installation problem

Tags: linux, kali-linux, troubleshooting

I'm dual booting with Kali 2 and Windows 10.

The problem is that i encountered this error:

error: file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod not found.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>

At first, i was successfully dual booted with Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04 and then i tried something new, and didn't realized that this will happen. Before that problem occurred, I had installed Windows 10 successfully with a bootable flash drive, and tried to install Kali2 alongside with it, while in installation progress, the installation using graphical install doesn't continue in the part of installing and retrieving Package Manager so i restarted it by pressing ++ and then i tried  to access the BIOS and it shows up, so i retried to reinstall it hoping that it will be successful the next time but when it again still stucked at that part, the Package Manager, and i again do the restarting and unplugging the USB flash drive method but this time, and this time I changed the legacy into UEFI in  the BIOS for me to access the windows to check whether my Windows is affected , but when i tried now to reinstall the kali and got stuck up with the same problem and i restarted it once more, and now by this time I can't access the BIOS, and my bootable USB flash drive doesn't work or recognizable, when i inserted CD/DVD, it slows down booting, i think it reads something, so i tried to insert Windows 10 CD, it reads for a second but bypass after, and tried and tried keys to access BIOS once more but it doesnt work, some tell me it has locked down and have become in fast boot method.

When i tried to use ls command in the grub rescue this shows up
(hd0), (hd0,msdos6), (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1)

when i tried ls(hd0,msdos5), it responded with a Filesystem is ext2, and when tried ls with the others, it responded Filesystem is unknown.

I tried also the command insmod linux and insmod normal with other parameters and still it doesn't work

My laptop is lenovo Z500, and my one key doesnt work due it had removed it i order to have a successful dual booting for Ubuntu and Windows 10